# Http Get call never reaches backend yet URL works in browser. Error "is not valid JSON"

Tags: angular, http, url

The backend function works: Postman and Swagger call it fine.

I captured the URL string shown in the error and pasted it in a browser; it reaches the backend and returns data correctly.

```
 getSelectedUser(nxtId: number) {
    var url = this.baseUrl + `Users/GetUserById/${nxtId}`;
    this.http.get<memberDto>( url ) <------------ see URL below
      .subscribe({
      next: (response: memberDto) =>
      {
        var x = response;
      },
      error: (err) =>
      {
        console.log(err.error.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

The url is:

```
https://localhost:7270/api/Users/GetUserById/13
```

Once the http request is sent, it comes back immediately to the error, which claims it isn't JSON!

Adding network tab here (doesn't make sense to me), but getallusers is the function where this occurs:
[image]

This shows nxtId is in fact 13:
[image]
Stepped to next line and snapshot shows this again:
[image]

Comment: can you also share the JSON (payload) ?

Comment: It probably isn't valid JSON. Check your network tab and share the result.

Answer (score -1):

Try test this value before you send it: `Users/GetUserById/${nxtId}`; I suspect the value of Users/GetUserById/${nxtId} is not the same as /13

```
console.log(${nxtId});
```

Check the log to see what the value you're sendng is. Why? because if you're raising an error it's probably not in JSON format.